# Complex Analysis Notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, complex-numbers, notation

What does the symbol $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$ mean? Here, $\Bbb C$ is the domain of complex numbers and the context is showing complex numbers follow pretty much the same rules as real calculus.

Comment: You need to provide more context.

Comment: Do you mean $C_0$, $C\{0\}$, $C(0)$ (respectively `C_0`, `C\{0\}`, `C(0)`)?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You haven't given us enough context. Please [edit] the question to provide a whole sentence where that appears. Use mathjax formatting: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Sorry about the typo. Its C\{0}

Comment: @Shvetu That is the set of nonzero complex numbers.

Comment: @Shvetu $\setminus$ is just the conventional "set minus" operator. $A \setminus B$ denotes the set of all elements of $A$ that are not in $B$.

Comment: @Shvetu Thanks for clarifying; I've added MathJax to your question.

Comment: @Shvetu See here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Answer (score 5):

For any two sets $A$ and $B$, $A\setminus B$ is the set of those elements of $A$ that don't belong to $B$.

In particular, $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}=\{z\in\mathbb C\,|\,z\neq0\}$.

Comment: +1 for teaching me the difference between `\setminus` and `\backslash` viz. $\setminus$ and $\backslash$.